# Unable to import folder with subfolder pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a working directory with the folder structure below:

```
main folder
 subfolder1
   subsubfolder2
```

I am trying to import subfolder 2 from the python console.

```
from subfolder1 import subfolder2
```

Pycharm is throwing a import module error. There are `__init__.py` files in each of the folders, and I have marked each of these folder as source.
I am not sure why I am still getting the import module error.

I am using pycharm community edition 2018

Comment: Are you trying to import a python module from subfolder2? In that case it would be `from subfolder1.subfolder2 import module` Also where are you starting the python console from? What directory?

Comment: Are you trying too import a python file or module from a folder? Because I don't think importing a subfolder is possible.  And your import will depend on which directory you are currently working on. Please make sure that your project directory and the main folder directory are same

Comment: yes i  am trying to import the module from the subdirectory and my python console is starting from the same directory as where this module is stored

Comment: as i was playing around with the settings, it seemed to work in the end. it could be due to the directory settings.